# Plotly-px. plot: Sharing x- axis plotting different y-values with button choice and all belonging to the same figure- How?

Tags: python, plotly

I cannot load correctly for every button the corresponding columns defined in the fig command line because in all buttons is shown the info regarding to the command line with x = ‘date’ and y = ‘confirmed’.
Could please someone tell me how to define/ associate the info of the ‘fig’ to the corresponding button and combined all together to get something like the following plot and when you click on the button you can see the adequate y-values?

```py
import pandas as pd

countries_agg = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datasets/covid-19/master/data/countries-aggregated.csv') 
df = countries_agg 
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('Date','date') 
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('Country','country') 
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('Confirmed','confirmed') 
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('Recovered','recovered') 
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('Deaths','deaths')
```

```py
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.line(df, x = 'date', y = 'deaths', color = 'country', title='Evolution') 
fig = px.line(df, x = 'date', y = 'recovered', color = 'country', title='Evolution') 
fig = px.line(df, x = 'date', y = 'confirmed', color = 'country', title='Evolution') 
fig.update_xaxes(
    rangeslider_visible=True, 
    rangeselector=dict(
        buttons=list([
             dict(count=1, label="Confirmed", step="month", stepmode="backward"),                  
             dict(count=6, label="Recovered", step="month", stepmode="backward"),                       
             dict(count=1, label="Deaths", step="month", stepmode="todate"),
                     ])
        )
    ) 
fig.show()
```

Image:

[image]

Comment: It's hard to work with a screenshot of code, could you include your code with your question?  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: [This](https://plotly.com/python/custom-buttons/) info on plotly custom buttons might help.

Comment: @jayveesea, thanks for the link. I have also tried with the info that you suggested me following the example 'Update Button' but unfortunately the values of the y-axes are not updated. I do not know what else I should try.  Do you have any other recommendation?

Comment: can you include your code (not a picture of the code) and the data source?

Comment: Thanks @jayveesa. First,Thank you for your help. Sure, the data source and the 1st part: countries_agg = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datasets/covid-19/master/data/countries-aggregated.csv')
df = countries_agg df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('Date','date')
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('Country','country')
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('Confirmed','confirmed')
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('Recovered','recovered')
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('Deaths','deaths')fig = px.line(df, x = 'date', y = 'deaths', color = 'country', title='Evolution')

Comment: fig = px.line(df, x = 'date', y = 'recovered', color = 'country', title='Evolution')
fig = px.line(df, x = 'date', y = 'confirmed', color = 'country', title='Evolution')
fig.update_xaxes(
    rangeslider_visible=True,
    rangeselector=dict(
        buttons=list([
            dict(count=1, label="Confirmed", step="month", stepmode="backward"),
            dict(count=6, label="Recovered", step="month", stepmode="backward"),
            dict(count=1, label="Deaths", step="month", stepmode="todate"),
                    ])
    )
)
fig.show()

Comment: ok, thx, I added your code to your question.  the link to the data seems broken.

Comment: ok, I think this is it: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datasets/covid-19/master/data/countries-aggregated.csv

Comment: Yes, I was trying now to paste it again. That is the dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this can be done with `plotly express`.  With your code as-is, each call to `fig = px.line...` is overwriting the previous call.  BUT, with `plotly go` it is more clear how to achieve your desired result.

Here is an example using `plotly go` that:

- Loops through the countries and plots all the traces (death, recovery, confirmed), but only death visible
- Creates visibility lists for the buttons.
- Maps those visibility lists to a button.

Using `df` we can plot:

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

fig = go.Figure()
visDth, visRec, visCon = [], [], []

countries = np.unique(df.country)
for i in countries:
    msk = df.country==i
    #add trace for each country, making only death visible
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df.date[msk], y=df.deaths[msk], name=i, visible=True))
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df.date[msk], y=df.recovered[msk], name=i, visible=False))
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df.date[msk], y=df.confirmed[msk], name=i, visible=False))
    #update visible lists, one for each button
    visDth.extend([True,False,False])
    visRec.extend([False,True,False])
    visCon.extend([False,False,True])

#update layout with a button and reference the visble list
fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        dict(
            type="buttons", direction="right",
            active=0, x=0.57, y=1.2,
            buttons=list([
                dict(label="Deaths",
                     method="update",
                     args=[{"visible": visDth}]),
                dict(label="Confimred",
                     method="update",
                     args=[{"visible":visRec}]),
                dict(label="Recovered",
                     method="update",
                     args=[{"visible":visCon}])]))])

fig.show()
```